# What are all the "conventions" for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

I'm a Django person going into Rails, and I want a guide that shows me all the popular "conventions".

For example: plurality, _form.html.erb, stuff like that.

Can someone list them here? Or a webpage?

Answer (score 9):

If you want the official conventions, then nothing beats the original Rails book:
[Agile Web Development with Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356549)

But if you want the unwritten conventions, here's a good start:
[acts_as_good_style](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2007/08/actsasgoodstyle.html)

Answer (score 5):

**Rails:**
**Rails Style Guide** : https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide
**Ruby Style Guide** : https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide
Rails Best Practises : http://rails-bestpractices.com

There used to be a "*Complete Guide to Rails Plugins (2 part article) :*" but site is gone now    http://nubyonrails.com/articles/the-complete-guide-to-rails-plugins-part-i

**Ruby:**
**Ruby From Other Languages :** https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages
**Ruby Language Tips, Tricks, Dos and Don'ts and Gotchas :** http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html

Another way to understand mysterious workings of a framework is to understand the principles and implementation details on which it is built. Internals often dictate why something must be just-so. "Rebuilding Rails" is a book which claims to give this X-Ray vision into Rails internals. It's available for a price though. Might be cheaper to just browse the source-code with source-insight or some Rails IDE instead.

The book 'The Rails Way' is a good insight into different aspects of WHY Rails is the way it is.

Chapter 18 onwards of the book "Agile Web Development with Rails" talks about Rails module-by-module i.e. "what each module does, how to extend or even replace the module and why you'd even want to do so".

Many of the "magic"/conventions arise by using Ruby Meta-programming features you might find Pragmatic Programmers book [Meta-programming Ruby - Program like the Ruby Pros](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476) useful.

Though not accessible for a novice programmer more intermediate/advanced programmers can browse the Rails source code at [Github Rails Repository](https://github.com/rails/rails)

Answer (score 3):

I'm finding [rails-bestpractices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/) to be increasingly useful although always read the comments as some of the advice is debatable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if anyone can list them, at least off the top of their heads.  "Conventions" in rails just means the default behavior for a given feature.  Most features have sane conventions, and most likely what you were intending to do.  For example, in Rails 3, ERB's <%= something %> construct automatically escapes HTML, because 99% of the time that's what you'll want to do.

I suggest just keep learning.  With conventions, there's a lot less to remember when you're learning because of these conventions.  Conventions just become "the rails way" and if you ever need to do something outside of them, *then* you look up how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the site 
http://www.rubyonrails.org
This will help you get around the concepts of RoR

Comment: And http://guides.rails.info/ too.