# How to get Proper idea about Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, activerecord, rake

Hi I am from PHP background and in am not really very familiar with these command line process and idea about operation of Rails applications. I want to get fine idea about what is this Activerecord, REST and other important task such as Rake is, more precisely what is this 'task' in Rails anyway. I have been seeing these online screen casts about Rails and I get the idea how to make it work but don't quite know how does that really work, they just extend the class activerecord and use it to their app by making custom class but what is this activerecord, I am really very confused and I am having hard time getting rails inside my brain but I really really want to learn it. Is there any suitable resource to idea idea from basic. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203288/how-does-ruby-on-rails-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Get the "Agile Web Development with Ruby on Rails" book.  Also consider getting several of the O'Reilly Rails book.  Also the pragmatic programmer books on Ruby/Rails are great.

2) Join a user group if there is one in your area.

3) Base your education on your background.  If you don't know OO(Object Oriented) programming, focus on ruby, if you do (java/c) background focus on the db.  If you have both, focus on the view.  PHP developers may find http://pragprog.com/book/ndphpr/rails-for-php-developers useful,l though it is from 2008 (Rails 2) and currently out of print so you'll need to search.

4) Make 3 or 4 applications to learn from.

5) Know that a lot of the errors you'll see are very cryptic for newbies.  Don't Panic!

6) Screencasts are good, as you have found.  Peepcode's (paid, e.g. $8-12 but worth it).

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) by Michael Hartl is a good free online resource to help you get into Rails development.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few segments from the texts i've been learning from.
I am new to not only Rails, but OOP as well.

http://www.sitepoint.com/learn-ruby-on-rails-9/

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

I also have "Agile Web Development with Rails" as another person mentioned. It's golden, as is anything else in "The Pragmatic Programers" series, i've found.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

http://railsforzombies.org/

A very nice series of screencasts on the very basics of Rails development. Comes with a great exercise platform that allows you to start practicing in your browser, without necessity of command line tools.

After you get a grasp you may check out [this book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).
It covers a wide variety of topics, is very accessible, and even tries to solve any potential problems you may run onto.

It's probably not a good idea to start by extending a core class :)

Answer (score 0):

Rails is a framework. Ruby is the language.

It sounds as if you need to start learning the ruby language. If you stay at the Rails level you will always get that feeling of "not quite knowing how things really work". A bit like trying to learn Drupal or Wordpress without knowing enough PHP first.

I recommend the rubykoans for learning ruby:

http://rubykoans.com/

Comment: appreciate it, i know i feel the same way. Thankyou

Comment: that route is good but may not fit all.  Ruby languished mostly in obscurity for 10 years until Rails.  Some developers need a more visual 'thing' to be interested other than just code.  Other are the opposite.  Different strokes for different folks 'an all.