# Rails from the inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

All this guildes and books are aimed at developing website, but what if I want to understand how Rails work? Is there any articles about how does my app starts, how does ActionView works with my layouts and so on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only site about rails internals I have found in my bookmarks is http://railsguts.com/, and it is about Rails 2.3. There is also an excellent screencast about the Rails 3 routing: http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough

There is also this question which can give you additional hints: [How does ruby on rails work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203288/how-does-ruby-on-rails-work)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. But seems like there is a big difference between 2.3 and 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails guides explain things like that:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

But in order for you to really understand how Rails is working - than you need to build an application.  That's why most of the tutorials on Rails start with making a project.

This is a free book that will walk you through just about everything you need to know about Rails to get started:  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

In my humble opinion, building an actual application is a great way to learn how all the pieces work together.

**EDIT:**

Based on your response below, it seems like you are looking for a deep understanding of exactly how Rails works and not just a working knowledge.  The only way you can really do this is by digging through the source code - like Archit suggested:  https://github.com/rails/rails

You can however get a more advanced understanding of how things work by using this book:  [http://www.amazon.com/Rails-AntiPatterns-Refactoring-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321604814](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814).  It does a good job of explaining a lot of the "magic" that Rails is known for.

... but you will never know exactly how things work unless you peruse the source.

Comment: I can build apps and they work, but I don't understand why and how they work. For example I don't really understand how does Rails autoload classes and cache them.

Comment: wow Thank you for the book. Preview seems rather cool, will order it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe so. Probably because you can always just go read the code @ github (https://github.com/rails/rails)

Comment: Yes, but this is too front reception.